# Is the action of $SO(2)$ on $R^2$ faithful?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, orthogonal-matrices

My question deals with the action of $SO(2)$ on $R^2$. I need to determine whether it is transitive/2-transitive/faithful/free or not.
I know it's not transitive, because we can take any two points with different lengths, and there aren't any matrices that will transfer $x_1$ to $x_2$ since orthogonal matrices preserve norm.
It is not 2-transitive since it is not transitive.
In addition, it is not free since $(0,0)$ is a fixed point for every matrix.
However, I couldn't determine what about faithfulness. I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you recall the definition of faithfulness ? Can you see why any subgroup of $\mathfrak SX$ (the group of bijections of $X$) always acts faithfully on $X$ ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I actually didn't think of $SO(2)$ as a group of bijections, but if so, it must be faithful, because otherwise it will contradict injetcivity?

Comment: Well it sort of depends on how you defined $SO(2)$, but injectivity is clearly equivalent to seeing it as a group of bijections, so we wouldn't want to use that unless we know it for a fact. But if, e.g., you know that $GL_2(\mathbb R)\cong GL(\mathbb R^2)$, then it follows immediately.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I didn't know it, but I can see why $GL_2(R)≅GL(R^2)$.However, why does it follow immediately?

Comment: Well $GL(\mathbb R^2)$ is defined as a subgroup of $\mathfrak S \mathbb R^2$ (those bijections that are linear), so any subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ (in our case, $SO(2)$ if you defined it as matrices) corresponds to a subgroup of $GL(\mathbb R^2)$, so of $\mathfrak S\mathbb R^2$, so it acts faithfully (you need to check that the action is the correct one but that's essentially obvious from the isomorphism you choose). But that's why it depends : did you define $SO(2)$ as a matrix group, or as a permutation group ?

Comment: (of course the 2 are essentially the same, via the given isomorphism, but the wording of a proof would slightly change depending on your definition)

Comment: @MaximeRamzi It's defined as the matrix group

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I think I understood now what you meant. Thank you very much for your help! (: